# Saving a dataset through a function, but it is not loaded afterwards

Tags: r, function, file-upload

I have created a function that reads some text data from a certain file, does some manipulation (omitted here) and then saves each modified dataframe in this list as `.RData`. I have checked that the function does its job. However, when loading the output again into RStudio, the `load` command runs without errors, but there is no new object in my environment.

Any possible fixes?

```
f <- function(directory_input, directory_output, par1, par2){
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
if(dir.exists(directory_output) == F) {
        dir.create(directory_output)
      }
      key <- data.frame(par= as.character(paste0(0, par1, par2)))
      paths <- key %>%  mutate(
        filepath_in = file.path(directory_input, paste0(par, '.txt'), sep = ''),
        filepath_out = file.path(directory_output, paste0(par, '.RData'), sep = '')
      )

    filepath_in <- paths$filepath_in
    filepath_out <- paths$filepath_out

    DF <- filepath_in %>% map( ~ .x %>% read.delim2(., encoding = 'Latin-1', nrows = 1000))
    map2(DF, filepath_out, ~ .x %>% save(file = .y))

}
```

**EDIT**

After the comments, here is a bit more of context:

I was instructed to write a function that will be part of a future package.
The function does not create a new dataframe, only saves it in the computer. I designed in order to make it easier for the user in case he is manipulating multiple datasets.

On the other hand, it is natural to assume that the user would use these datasets in the future in the most intuitive way, using only `load`. So that is why it wouldn't be ideal to have a solution that requires using `assign` to load the results in the future.

Comment: you need to `return(DF)` in your function `f()`

Comment: @EJJ but where does the command goes? After the ```map2``` command? Inside it?

Comment: You may need to assign (using `assign()`) the object when you load it, if it already exists somewhere else.

Comment: @KevinCazelles is there an alternative? Because this function would not be for me to use, but for a package I am writing. In such case, users wouldn't actually figure this out by themselves, I guess

Comment: It depends on how the object saved will be used. If it isn't an object to be placed in the `data` folder, then you have several options (using `saveRDS()` / `readRDS()` for instance). If you describe the expected workflow (where the data should be saved, why users will need to save and load the data, ...), we might be able to help you more.

Comment: @KevinCazelles please refer to the edited question

Comment: If the data are always the same and relatively small, I would add them in the package. If the function is designed to work with various data set, I would opt for the RDS approach. If you'd rather stick to `save()`/`load()` I would suggest you add a helper function in your package to properly load the data. This is a personal opinion, other may proceed otherwise.

Comment: I have replaced ```save``` by ```saveRDS```... but this would still not allow me to read the data afterwards with ```load```, right?